# How can vectors depend on position?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

When I first learned about euclidean spaces and affine geometry, I was told that a cartesian coordinate system in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a pair ($O,\mathcal{B}$) where $O$ is the origin, a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an affine space, and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Later, though, I was introduced to curvilinear coordinate systems, which are kind of the same but with basis vectors that change depending on their position. That seems to contradict the idea that I had of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which was that they can be geometrically interpreted as arrows attatched only to the origin.

How is the idea of vectors depending on position formalised, then?

Comment: As vector fields.

Comment: If you are familiar with the axioms of a vector space then the points in $\mathbb R^n$ form a vector space. We think of them as arrows rooted at the origin but you can just as well think of $\mathbb R^n$ as a set of points with addition and scalar multiplication defined. When we use vectors to describe coordinate systems at a point on a curve or surface we define a coordinate system called a tangent space. This looks like $\mathbb R^n$ but its origin is the point on the curve or surface.

Comment: As a (smooth) local moving frame: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_frame) i.e. a set of (smooth) local sections of the tangent bundle which, at each point of an open set of a manifold, form a basis of the tangent space (the fiber) at that point.

Comment: Anyway, your question is unclear; are you referring to local coordinates on a smooth manifold, like space-time in GR, for example?

Comment: @green.onion true, I could've been more specific. I was referring to the "usual" curvilinear coordinate systems, the ones one would use to represent a curve or a surface in geometry or calculus, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formalisms of affine geometry are quite different from the ones used in the study of general manifolds. There is no need to consider vectors in every point of space when studying affine geometry because a single basis is enough to cover all space, but when studying differential geometry and physics it becomes necessary to consider "local" coordinates, and thus local vector basis.

So, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or any other topological space, we can define a  $\mathbb{R}$-vector space "attatched" to every point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We call that space a tangent space, and we denote it $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$.
Its elements are pairs of the form $(p,v)$, with $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ interpreted as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space; and they can be geometrically interpreted as arrows with its origin on $p$.

In fact, we can define a tangent space to every point of any differentiable manifold $\mathcal{V}$, so that the points $p+v$ with $(p,v)\in T_p\mathcal{V}$ form the linear manifold tangent to $\mathcal{V}$ at $p$. That's why it's called a **tangent** space.

The disjoint union of all the sets $T_p\mathcal{V}$ with $p\in\mathcal{V}$ is called the tangent bundle of $\mathcal{V}$, $T\mathcal{V}$.

Now that we have defined all this, a vector which changes depending on its position is just a vector field, a function $v\space\colon\space \mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow T\mathbb{R}^n$ which maps a point $p$ of the topological space $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a vector $(p,w) \in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$